# What is underlay and overlay network?

Tags: network, terminology

Curios to know about underlay and overlay networks and differences between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Underlay network is a physical infrastructure that is responsible to deliver packets for you. On the other hand Overlay network is a virtual network that is built on top of an underlay. For example, you can imagine that the links between ISPs that create the Internet formed an underlay network and your Site-to-Site VPN, on top of it, is an overlay.